# Array allocation - can you stop constructors and destructors from being called?

Tags: c++

I'm in the unfortunate position to write my own vector implementation (no, using a standard implementation isn't possible, very unfortunately). The one which is used by now uses raw bytes buffers and in-place construction and deconstruction of objects, but as a side-effect, I can't look into the actual elements. So I decided to do a variant implementation which uses internally true arrays.

While working on it I noticed that allocating the arrays would cause additional calls of construtor and destructor comapred to the raw buffer version. Is this overhead somehow avoidable without losing the array access? It would be nice to have it as fast as the raw buffer version, so it could be replaced.

I'd appreciate as well if someone knows a good implementation which I could base my own on, or the very least get some ideas from. The work is quite tricky after all. :)

Edit:

Some code to explain it better.

```
T* data = new T[4]; // Allocation of "num" elements
data[0] = T(1);
data[1] = T(2);
delete[] data;
```

Now for each element of the array the default constructor has been called, and then 2 assignment methods are called. So instead just 2 constructor calls we have 4 and later 4 destructor calls instead just 2.

Comment: look at any open implementation of std::vector and refactor it for your needs, it's really uncomplicated.

Comment: Can you give some code, which demonstrates the allocation, and what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: If your container can hold any type of object, the people using your container (even if it is some maintenance programmer inheriting your code in the future) are very reasonable to assume that the ctor/dtor will be called.  If they don't want those to do anything, due to the overhead, they're free to define a ctor/dtor that is a no-op, such as a POD type.  If they want to use less-plain objects, but avoid expensive copying, they can create a container of pointers instead.  That's why the standard containers work the way they do.

Answer (score 2):

> as a side-effect, I can't look into the actual elements.

Why not?

```
void* buffer = ...
T* elements = static_cast<T*>(buffer);
std::cout << elements[0] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I've tried to look into the contents, but I don't see anything past the internal pointer. When I try to use [] in the debugger it complains about being unable to call a function. Also I can't simply in all situations add code which extracts the right element, and that's assuming I'd know which one in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using true arrays means constructors will be called. You'll need to go to raw byte buffers - but it's not too bad. Say you have a buffer:

```
void *buffer;
```

Change that to a `T *`:

```
T *buffer;
```

When allocating, treat it as a raw memory buffer:

```
buffer = (T *) malloc(sizeof(T) * nelems);
```

And call constructors as necessary:

```
new(&buffer[x]) T();
```

Your debugger should be able to look into elements of the buffer as with a true array. When it comes time to free the array, of course, it's your responsibility to free the elements of the array, then pass it to `free()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nInUse; i++)
    buffer[x].~T();
free((void*)buffer);
```

Note that I would not use `new char[]` and `delete[]` to allocate this array - I don't know if `new char[]` will give proper alignment, and in any case you'd need to be careful to cast back to `char*` before `delete[]`ing the array.

Comment: A clean implementation of this pattern can be found in the allocator interface (and in the default allocator, `std::allocator`).

Comment: Why can't you use placement new?

Comment: you can't call a constructor (constructor is a special function without a name), you need to use placement new to construct an object in raw memory.

Comment: Right, fixed. I keep forgetting that :)

Comment: @bdonlan In fact using `new char[]` is completely safe. See 5.3.4/10 "For arrays of char and unsigned char, the difference between the result of the new expression and the address returned by the allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the most stringent alignment requirement (3.9) of any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created. [Note: ...this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed. ]"

Comment: @Mark, ah, interesting, okay, so `new char[]` is fine then. I still won't recommend it - too easy to accidentally forget the cast on the delete side...

Comment: "Your debugger should be able to look into elements of the buffer as with a true array." Don't know if that is a limitation of Windows CE target side, but I can't. I tried already. :(

Comment: @Johannes, sounds like a limitation of your debugger, then :/

Answer (score 1):

I find the following implementation quite interesting: [C Array vs. C++ Vector](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/c-array-vs-c-vector/)

Besides the performance comparison, his vector implementation also includes push/pop operations on the vector.

[The code](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/kvec.h.html) also has an example that shows how to use the macros:

```
#include "kvec.h"
int main() {
    kvec_t(int) array;
    kv_init(array);
    kv_push(int, array, 10); // append
    kv_a(int, array, 20) = 5; // dynamic
    kv_A(array, 20) = 4; // static
    kv_destroy(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The dude wrote the entire vector interface using macros. Let's give him some credit, shall we?

Comment: the only credit for that is being shot on the spot, so no other such abomination can come out of him.